# Proxy configuration issue in GIT and node

Tags: node.js, git, proxy, npm, ntlm

I have to configure NTLM proxy authentication for GIT and node js for npm. But i am not able to achieve it at all.

I tried configuring it for git like this

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@ip:port
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@ip:port
```

And for npm like

```
proxy = http://username:password@ip:port
https-proxy = http://username:password@ip:port
```

I tried mentioning the domain name also for both git and npm but its not working

```
http://domain\\username:password@ip:port
```

I am working in windows 7.

For git, I am using git bash.
For npm, command prompt.

The only thing works is when i tried curl from git bash using the format below

```
curl -x, --proxy-ntlm --proxy http://username:password@ip:port http://www.google.co.in
```

Why GIT and npm install is not working while i am able to get the response through CURL.

What am i doing wrong?

Update:
1. It's and active directory domain.
2. I cant install CNTLM its blocked.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for the git part, might be related to several ntlm related commits.

In msysgit 1.9.5, it works without explicit username and password.

[git client using GSSAPI for NTLM proxy authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338620/git-client-using-gssapi-for-ntlm-proxy-authentication)