# git client using GSSAPI for NTLM proxy authentication

Tags: git, curl, github, proxy, ntlm

Like many, Im trying to access github.com from behind a corporate proxy.

Apparently* curl (via libcurl) now includes GSSAPI support for NTLM proxy authentication without having to manually divulge username and password.

Since git client uses libcurl, I assume this is accessible via git.

How do I access this using git client ?

(*) See [NTLM proxy without password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276955/ntlm-proxy-without-password), for a discussion of ntlm proxy authentication without providing the password.

See also [Using Libcurl to authenticate ntlm proxy without pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585186/using-libcurl-to-authenticate-ntlm-proxy-without-pass).

Answer (score 12):

In the end I had to RTFS, the answer in summary:

As at msysgit version 1.9.5 (earlier versions are untested), git

1. uses the proxy configuration for [http] section for both http and https
2. does NOT have an explicit way to set authentication type (such as ntlm)
3. does NOT have a separate way to set username and password other than embedded in the proxy url
4. using an empty username and password works, so it will use default NTLM credentials if you do the following

   git config --global http.proxy `https://:@proxyhost:proxyport/`

Note that the `:` and `@` that delimit the username and password are present, but the fields are empty. And it seems to accept using https to connect to proxy.

Comment: +1 for mentioning to let user name and password empty to use current Windows user for authenticating to proxy server. As an addition, use `git config --global http.http://hostToBeNotConnectedViaProxy/.proxy ""` to avoid connection via proxy to git repository servers inside the corporate network.